# Javascript lookback 1 folder to get image of parent Directory

Tags: javascript, directory, parent

My site layout (for this example):

```
localhost/mydomain/
-localhost/mydomain/pics
-localhost/mydomain/somepages/arandompage.php
```

I want to access picture from here:

```
localhost/mydomain/index.php
```

I did this:

```
<img id='4' src='pics/somepic.1.jpg'>
```

The mouseover snippet:

```
{ $('#'+someId).attr('src', 'pics/somepic.'+num+'.jpg');
```

This is working. But when I wanted to access it from here it doesn’t work.
But when you go `localhost/mydomain/somepages/arandompage.php` it obviously doesn't work, no longer relative.

```
<img id='4' src='../pics/somepic.1.jpg'>
```

Ok here obviously that'll fix the display image.
It is not working in JavaScript.

```
{ $('#'+videoId).attr('src', '../pics/somepic.'+num+'.jpg'); /
```

I don't know what to do here, but yes all I need is the JavaScript to just look back 1 folder to get that img src. That's all. If you answer please insert what should be here in:

```
`{ $('#'+videoId).attr('src', ====> 'pics/somepic.'+num+'.jpg');`
```

So that it goes to the parent directory.

P.S. I tried absolute paths but to no avail either.

Comment: *"I have tried an searched everywhere to simply just get the javascript to go up 1 directory..."* That's what the `../` in your example **does**. Why do you think that isn't working?

Comment: Fire up Chrome, press F12, go to `Network` tab, type your script's URL in address tab and see, what exact location it thinks your image is at.

Comment: Let's check what is the result of this code in Elements inspector (CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome).

Comment: hahahahahahaaaa.. I'll take dumbass 2013 award please. My mysql search loop was outputting a nonexisting img folder with a non existing img file to all my result imgs...Thanks for the chrome info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is to remember what the *browser's* view of the hierarchy is:

1. Assuming `localhost/mydomain` is the **root** of your site, then:

   ...a page like `localhost/mydomain/somepage.php`:

   - will appear at e.g. `http://example.com/somepage.php` from the browser's POV
   - and can use `pics/somepic.jpg` or `/pics/somepic.jpg` for the pic.

   ...a page like `localhost/mydomain/somepages/somepage.php`:

   - will appear at e.g. `http://example.com/somepages/somepage.php` from the browser's POV
   - and can use `../pics/somepic.jpg` or `/pics/somepic.jpg` for the pic.
2. Assuming `localhost` is the root of your site instead, then:

   ...a page like `localhost/mydomain/somepage.php`

   - will appear at e.g., `http://example.com/mydomain/somepage.php` from the browser's POV
   - and can use `pics/somepic.jpg` or `/mydomain/pics/somepic.jpg` for the pic.

   ...a page like `localhost/mydomain/somepages/somepage.php`

   - will appear at e.g., `http://example.com/mydomain/somepages/somepage.php` from the browser's POV
   - and can use `../../pics/somepic.jpg` or `/mydomain/pics/somepic.jpg` for the pic.